# Model, Performing an OR and a ordered by

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
Class Category(models.Model):
    ....

Class CategoryProduct(models.Model):
    ....
    position  = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)


class Product(models.Model):
    .....
```

I am performing the following query:

```
return Product.objects.filter(categoryproduct__category=self, active=True) | \
           Product.objects.filter(categoryproduct__category__category=self, active=True)
```

How do I get the position ordered by categoryproduct__position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a better time "concatenating" your queries with [Q object instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
Product.objects.filter(Q(categoryproduct__category=self) | Q(categoryproduct__category__category=self), active=True)
```